# How is it Instagram shows heads-up notifications when app is in background?

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

As far as I googled if an app is in background notifications drop in a tray and can't be shown as heads-up overlaying all other apps. But yet instagram notifications overlay other apps even when instagram not in the foreground. How do they do this? I managed to show heads-up notification on emulator but only when my app is in the foreground and couldn't do the same on my real device (Huawei). Android on device and emulator are the same - 5.1

Can it be connected with a source of notifications? I am using firebase console to send notifications. Probably it's firebase restriction and I should switch to onesignal or another provider?

Also, are heads-up notification can only be singleline, or I can somehow enable multiline mode?

Please, give me working code for heads-up notifications when app is in the background. I already tested everything I could find on StackOverflow on the matter.

Comment: try to use JPush Notification but it is a Chinese version. See this link https://github.com/jpush

Answer (score 0):

That might be the case of OS force closing background services. Some manufacturers like Huawei, Xiaomi etc, do that intentionally to enhance battery life. But for apps like Instagram and Whatsapp, manufacturers whitelist these apps.

To whitelist any App you have to change settings from the device itself.

To change settings for your app here is the [link](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-show-successful-but-are-not-being-shown#section-the-app-is-force-stopped).